# Final Form reset specific field value

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I have two Field components, a Parent and a Child. As Child is dependant on the Parent, I want to reset Child whenever Parent is updated.

I tried this:

```
           <Field name="parent">
              {(props) => {
                return (
                  <Parent
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                      props.input.onChange(newValue);
                      form.change('child', undefined);
                      form.resetFieldState('child');
                    }}
                    value={props.input.value}
                  />
                );
              }}
            </Field>
           <Field name="child">
              {(props) => {
                return (
                  <Child
                   value={props.input.value} // the value is not updated here,
                   onChange={props.input.onChange}
                  />
                );
              }}
            </Field>
```

but it does not seem to be working. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using form decorator, for example, having a form with two fields `firstName` and `lastName`, to reset `lastName` whenever `firstName` is changed you could:

```
<Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      initialValues={{ stooge: "larry", employed: false }}
      decorators={[
        (formApi) => {
          let before = formApi.getState();
          const unsubscribe = formApi.subscribe(
            (state) => {
              if (before.values.firstName !== state.values.firstName) {
                formApi.change("lastName", "");
              }
              before = state;
            },
            { values: true }
          );
          return unsubscribe;
        }
      ]}>...</Form>
```

in the example above, we subscribe for form state changes and compare the field value with the previous one, when it's changed, reset another one. Here is a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/so-final-form-reset-specific-field-value-drvr4l?file=/index.js:593-619

Oh, btw, there is ready-made package for this: https://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate